# In memory table query performance

Tags: sql-server, performance, query-performance

I am trying to optimize an sql query by using in memory tables. After I had ran the query some times I ran the Transaction Performance Analysis Overview report of SQL Server 2016 which suggested that I should optimize some tables. I chose to migrate to in memory the table with the biggest performance gain combined with the minimal migration work. However when I run the query using the in memory table it takes much more time than when using the disk based table.

Trying to troubleshoot it I ran the Top Resource Consuming Queries in query store where all the metrics except for duration are better for the query using the in memory table.

I would appreciate if anyone could advise me about this case and where should I search for the reason of this performance issue.

Edit: I added the query plans of a part of the complete query.

[image]

Comment: you may want to provide more details like old query execution plan,in memory query plan,hash buckets used

Comment: Execution plans? Schema?

Comment: In memory tables are very specific.   I had an application I thought they would help and they did not.

Comment: On the face of it, the in-memory plan isn't parallelised, but the on-disk one is. You might have a false equivalence here. We need FAR more information to assist you, as noted above.